# How to run a OSX application with OpenCV in a mac without OpenCV installed

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv, static-libraries, dynamic-library

I am developing a OSX application in Objective-C and OpenCV-2.4.12 using Xcode. 
I followed [this installation video guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37RvqZVddAw) and [this setup video guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVSPfUmNyOw) to integrate the OpenCV. Basically in the second video, the author uses the OpenCV dynamic libraries (.dylib files).

This work perfectly in my mac, but in another macs without OpenCV installed the application gives an error and I can´t open and run it.
I have searched and I think the solution is to use static libraries (.a files). But I can´t figure out how to replace the dynamic libraries with static libraries.

Which static libraries I need to use? Where I find them? How I link them in Xcode?

My settings right now:

I added to the project the *libopencv_core.2.4.12.dylib*, *libopencv_highgui.2.4.12.dylib*, *libopencv_imgproc.2.4.12.dylib*.

In the Search Paths I have (like explained in the second video):

- **Framework Search Paths:** /usr/local/lib
- **Header Search Paths:** /usr/local/include
- **Library Search Paths:** *"OpenCVFolderPath"*/build/lib

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to install OpenCV using `homebrew` and if I look at the options I can specify for OpenCV Version 3 like this:

```
brew options opencv3
```

I get this output:

```
--32-bit
    Build 32-bit only
--c++11
    Build using C++11 mode
--with-contrib
    Build "extra" contributed modules
--with-cuda
    Build with CUDA v7.0+ support
--with-examples
    Install C and python examples (sources)
--with-ffmpeg
    Build with ffmpeg support
...
...
--with-python3
    Build with python3 support
--with-qt
    Build the Qt4 backend to HighGUI
--with-qt5
    Build the Qt5 backend to HighGUI
--with-quicktime
    Use QuickTime for Video I/O instead of QTKit
--with-static                                         <--- *** HERE ***
    Build static libraries
--with-tbb
    Enable parallel code in OpenCV using Intel TBB
--with-vtk
    Build with vtk support
--without-eigen
    Build without eigen support
--without-numpy
    Use a numpy you've installed yourself instead of a Homebrew-packaged numpy
--without-opencl
    Disable GPU code in OpenCV using OpenCL
--without-openexr
    Build without openexr support
--without-python
    Build without Python support
--without-test
    Build without accuracy & performance tests
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

So, if I then go ahead and install like this:

```
brew install opencv3 --with-static
```

I end up with these static libraries which look like what you want:

```
ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/

-r--r--r--  1 mark  admin  1922864 21 Jul 14:23 libopencv_calib3d.a
-r--r--r--  1 mark  admin  3215896 21 Jul 14:23 libopencv_core.a
-r--r--r--  1 mark  admin   965336 21 Jul 14:23 libopencv_features2d.a
-r--r--r--  1 mark  admin   650552 21 Jul 14:23 libopencv_flann.a
-r--r--r--  1 mark  admin    60016 21 Jul 14:23 libopencv_highgui.a
-r--r--r--  1 mark  admin   378128 21 Jul 14:23 libopencv_imgcodecs.a
-r--r--r--  1 mark  admin  3946248 21 Jul 14:23 libopencv_imgproc.a
-r--r--r--  1 mark  admin   954296 21 Jul 14:23 libopencv_ml.a
-r--r--r--  1 mark  admin   542808 21 Jul 14:23 libopencv_objdetect.a
-r--r--r--  1 mark  admin  1078504 21 Jul 14:23 libopencv_photo.a
-r--r--r--  1 mark  admin   269248 21 Jul 14:23 libopencv_shape.a
-r--r--r--  1 mark  admin   694056 21 Jul 14:23 libopencv_stitching.a
-r--r--r--  1 mark  admin   193416 21 Jul 14:23 libopencv_superres.a
-r--r--r--  1 mark  admin   478776 21 Jul 14:23 libopencv_video.a
-r--r--r--  1 mark  admin   149040 21 Jul 14:23 libopencv_videoio.a
-r--r--r--  1 mark  admin   390288 21 Jul 14:23 libopencv_videostab.a
drwxr-xr-x  3 mark  admin      102 21 Jul 14:23 pkgconfig
drwxr-xr-x  3 mark  admin      102 21 Jul 14:23 python2.7
```

There doesn't appear to be an equivalent option with OpenCV2, though I am not sure why you would want to use that version.